# CMake macro to only run lupdate

Tags: qt, cmake

For a couple of reasons we need the ability to run lupdate on our sources, run a script on the resulting ts files, and then run lrelease. We're using CMake for our builds so a CMake macro would be nice.

But the only ones I see either just run lrelease, or run lupdate followed by lrelease. Is there one I'm missing to just run lupdate?

Thanks.

Comment: This may or may not help you: https://github.com/Cockatrice/Cockatrice/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 2):

You should use this guide:

https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/tutorials/How-To-Build-Qt4-Software

You could add some options in CMake to call only 'lupdate' depending on your requirements.

Note that QT4_ADD_TRANSLATION must be changed to QT5_ADD_TRANSLATION if you are working with Qt 5.